# Disable Android Market tracking of installs

Tags: android, google-play

I'm developing an Android application that will be hopefully used by activists around the world.  I'm somewhat dismayed that the Market automatically tracks active installs and sends crash reports, even though I'm not using analytics.  I'd rather that this usage information not be sent to Google at all (no matter how useful it might be to me as a developer).  I will offer my application for download from my own website, which is set to not log any downloads, but I'd like to turn this off on the Android market as well, but I don't see any option from the Market dashboard.

1. Is there a way to disable this programatically?
2. If I offer my signed apk from my own website, are these usage statistics also sent to Google?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Addind to Niek's reply, AFAIK it is not possible to disable tracking of active installs by  Google. In addition to offering your app to be downloaded from your site, you could check some alternatives to the Android market (google around, but here there are some of the main ones listed here: http://thenextweb.com/apps/2011/01/09/6-alternatives-to-the-android-market/). Depending on your user target, some people could find it easier to install from an alternate market. Of course, we don't know whether alternate markets track active installs...

Comment: Thanks for the info; I hadn't thought of posting it to other markets.

Answer (score 1):

For your second part, no. App crashes and other statistics are only applied to apps that are installed via the market. So offering your apk outside the market should do the trick.

Comment: Thanks for the info.  I still hope there's a way to disable the info for apps downloaded from the Market, as I bet many will find it through the market, but I'm betting Google doesn't make that an option.